# Is there a bounded linear function $F: L^{\infty}([-1,1]) \to \mathbb R$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Is there a bounded linear function $F: L^{\infty}([-1,1]) \to \mathbb R$ such that $F(u) = u(0)$ for u bounded and continuous at $0$?

BASIC ANALYSIS: the set of functions bounded and continuous at $0$ form a subspace. And such an operator is clearly bounded on this subspace. The next step might then be to show that this subspace is dense. Nonetheless, it seems not to be so since there is no such a function close to a step function which has a large gap at $0$. How should we analyze this problem then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is such a functional, using the Hahn-Banach Theorem.

Consider the subspace $W$ of $L^\infty[-1, 1]$ of functions that are continuous at $0$, and the map
$$\phi : W \to \mathbb{R} : u \mapsto u(0).$$
Note that the elements of $L^\infty[-1, 1]$ are equivalence classes and hence so are the elements of $W$, so we should make certain that $\phi$ is well-defined. The equivalence relation is being equal almost everywhere. So, if we have $u$ and $v$ are equal almost everywhere, then $u - v = 0$ almost everywhere. Hence, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, we cannot have $(u - v)(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$, which means we must have have a sequence $x_n \to 0$ such that $u(x_n) = v(x_n)$, and thus the limits to $0$ coincide. That is, $\phi$ is well-defined.

Using the algebra of limits, clearly $\phi$ is linear. All we have to do is show that $\phi$ is bounded. I claim that $\|\phi\| \le 1$ (indeed it's equal, but we don't need this). This is easy to see using much the same logic as the proof of well-definedness above. Essentially, there must be a sequence $x_n \to 0$ such that $|u(x_n)| \le \|u\|$, which proves by continuity that $|u(0)| \le  \|u\|$.

Now, we have that $|\phi| \le \|\cdot\|$, so by the Hahn-Banach theorem, there must exist an extension $\psi$ of $\phi$ to all of $L^\infty[-1, 1]$, still satisfying $|\psi| \le \| \cdot \|$ (i.e. bounded and of norm no greater than $1$) and $\psi(u) = u(0)$ for all $u \in W$.